# DNS, Top level domains

Tags: dns

OK so for sometime now, I thought top level domains are restricted to general words like. com .bid .edu, but then I saw  .barclays somewhere. Can these also just be registered or is it redirected in some way?

Comment: No reason this should've been voted down. Voting up to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

There was a window for TLD registration back in 2012. The resulting applications are still being processed, although over a thousand new TLDs have been delegated to date. You can read all about it [here](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/).